# Expandable View in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, toggle, expandable

Is there a way that I can achieve this in iOS.

for example when a user switch on a switch the view will automatically unhide itself or vice versa.

```
  *(UITextField)    (Switch)

           -(UITextField) //this is the view that will be hidden/unhidden

           -(UITextField) //this is the view that will be hidden/unhidden
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: make a clear question wat U require, get some screen shot

Comment: Set the view's hidden property to `YES` and `NO`

Comment: ok I'll add a screenshot

Comment: and if I set the hidden property to yes/no it only hides the view but the space allocated by it is there. I want something that the view automatically adjust if the view is hidden

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can hide / unhide views on tap on a switch. For example, you can use `UIButton` as a switch and hide your views in the implementation of an action method.

```
- (IBAction)handleButtonClick:(id)sender {
     self.subview1.hidden = YES;
     self.subview2.hidden - NO;
}
```

Here's a [good tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/xcode-tutorial-user-interaction/) which would help you to get started with `UIButton` and handling actions.

Alternatively, you can achieve the same using `UISwitch` instead. You may find this [tutorial](http://www.iosing.com/2011/11/uiswitch-lights-onoff/) useful.

**Update**: If you want to "expand" your subview, just update accordingly `frame` property of that particular subview.